# Temperature rests for hefeweizen

Tags: mash, mashing

I have an AG recipe for hefeweizen that I want to try.  It is 5 gallons, 9.5 lbs of grain, and I only have a 5 gallon picnic cooler tun. It calls for 3 temp rests and a mash out step.

My question is, will I have a problem starting out with a low water to grain ratio (say 0.7) in order to not over fill my tun with more than 5 gallons of water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you won't, but you also may not need all those rests.  That would make it easier for you.

Comment: I thought you needed the rests with Pilsner and wheat malt. Can you explain?

Comment: It pretty much depends on the malts you're using and the rests you want to do.  Most malts, including pilsner, are so well modified these days that not only do you not need a protein rest, but it can actually be detrimental to do one.  Some people like to do a p rest with wheat beer, but new research has shown that a lot of it depends on the % of wheat you use and other factors.  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/j.2050-0416.2004.tb00203.x/asset/j.2050-0416.2004.tb00203.x.pdf?v=1&t=hmwxnac6&s=4cca85e7b4c48ef5c636d1fee857168ec150cdd5.

Comment: If you feel like you really need a p rest, do it at 131, not the commonnly referenced 120-122F.  Using a higher temp and limiting it to 15 min. or less will minimize and possible damage to body or foam that may occur from a lower temp rest.  Doing steps for beta and alpha rests may or may not be worthwhile.  Many people find that using steps for those rests makes no difference in their beer.  But at least there is little chance of doing harm, unlike a p rest.  If you fly sparge, a mashout step may or may not be beneficial.   If you batch sparge, it's unnecessary.

Comment: If you REALLY want to do a step mash including a p rest. make sure you use undermodified malt.  That's not real easy to find these days.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the thorough explanation